# Can a token be removed from a spaCy document during pipeline processing?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using spaCy (a great Python NLP library) to process a number of very large documents, however, my corpus has a number of common words that I would like to eliminate in the document processing pipeline.  Is there a way to remove a token from the document within a pipeline component?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

spaCy's tokenization is **non-destructive**, so it always represents the original input text and never adds or deletes anything. This is kind of a core principle of the `Doc` object: you should *always* be able to reconstruct and reproduce the original input text.

While you *can* work around that, there are usually better ways to achieve the same thing without breaking the input text ↔ `Doc` text consistency. One solution would be to add a [custom extension attribute](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes) like `is_excluded` to the tokens, based on whatever objective you want to use:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Token

def get_is_excluded(token):
    # Getter function to determine the value of token._.is_excluded
    return token.text in ['some', 'excluded', 'words']

Token.set_extension('is_excluded', getter=get_is_excluded)
```

When processing a `Doc`, you can now filter it to only get the tokens that are not excluded:

```py
doc = nlp("Test that tokens are excluded")
print([token.text for token if not token._.is_excluded])
# ['Test', 'that', 'tokens', 'are']
```

You can also make this more complex by using the [`Matcher` or `PhraseMatcher`](http://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-matching) to find sequences of tokens in context and mark them as excluded.

Also, for completeness: If you do want to change the tokens in a [`Doc`](https://spacy.io/api/doc), you can achieve this by constructing a new `Doc` object with `words` (a list of strings) and optional `spaces` (a list of boolean values indicating whether the token is followed by a space or not). To construct a `Doc` with attributes like part-of-speech tags or dependency labels, you can then call the [`Doc.from_array`](https://spacy.io/api/doc#from_array) method with the attributes to set and a numpy array of the values (all IDs).