# How to modify spacy.tokens.doc.Doc tokens with pipeline components in SpaCy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I'm using SpaCy to pre-process some data. However, I'm stuck on how to modify the content of the `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` class.

For example, here:

```py
npc = spacy.load("pt")
def pre_process_text(doc) -> str:
    new_content = ""
    current_tkn = doc[0]
    for idx, next_tkn in enumerate(doc[1:], start=0):
        # Pre-process data
        # new_content -> currently, it is the way I'm generating
        # the new content, concatenating the modified tokens

    return new_content
nlp.add_pipe(pre_process_text, last=True)
```

In the comment part inside the above code, there are some tokens that I would like to remove from `doc` param, or I would like to change its token text content. In other words, I can modify the content of `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` by **(1)** removing tokens entirely, or **(2)** changing tokens contents.

Is there a way to create another `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` with those modified tokens but keeping the `Vocab` from the `npc = spacy.load("pt")`.

Currently, I'm generating the new content by returning a string, but is there a way to return the modified Doc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the core principles of spaCy's `Doc` is that it [should always represent the original input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617733/6400719):

> spaCy's tokenization is **non-destructive**, so it always represents the original input text and never adds or deletes anything. This is kind of a core principle of the `Doc` object: you should *always* be able to reconstruct and reproduce the original input text.
>
> While you *can* work around that, there are usually better ways to achieve the same thing without breaking the input text ↔ `Doc` text consistency.

I've outlined some approaches for excluding tokens without destroying the original input in [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617733/6400719).

Alternatively, if you really want to modify the `Doc`, your component could [create a new `Doc` object](https://spacy.io/api/doc#init) and return that. The `Doc` object takes a vocab (e.g. the original doc's vocab), a list of string `words` and an optional list of `spaces`, a list of booleans indicating whether the token at that position is followed by a space or not.

```py
from spacy.tokens import Doc

def pre_process_text(doc):
    # Generate a new list of tokens here
    new_words = create_new_words_here(doc)
    new_doc = Doc(doc.vocab, words=new_words)
    return new_doc
```

Note that you probably want to add this component **first** in the pipeline before other components run. Otherwise, you'd lose any linguistic features assigned by previous components (like part-of-speech tags, dependencies etc).

Comment: Say I want to lowercase the doc. What the line `new_doc=...` should be to ensure only lowercasing takes place?