# Python Spacy replace value of ent.label_ == PERSON with something else

Tags: python, replace, entity, spacy

I am using Python Spacy to replace any entity with the label_ == "PERSON" with "[XXX]".
It seems like I have done that correctly, but I am struggling with replacing it in my Teststring:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

file_text = """This is my teststring. Isaac Newton is supposed to be changed."""

nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities")

def change_names(file_text):
    text_doc = nlp(file_text)
    mylist = []
    for ent in text_doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
            print(ent)
            mylist.append("[XXX]")
        else:
            mylist.append(ent.text)
    res = ''.join(mylist)
    print(res)
    print(text_doc)

change_names(file_text)
```

This results in:

Isaac Newton
[XXX]
This is my teststring. Isaac Newton is supposed to be changed.

Result should be:
This is my teststring. [XXX] is supposed to be changed

Now I want to iterate over my text_doc and replace any ent with label_ == "PERSON" to "[XXX]". This is not working out for me. I tried using a double forloop for iterating over the string and if an item is an entity, jump into the for loop I posted here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't expect `Isaac Newton` to get changed, because you are not even trying to modify the `text_doc`. And if you try you will see [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57206316/3832970). You can only re-create a document. It makes it easier if you just wanted to obtain a *string* as output with the modified text.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do by appending it to a list and joining it into a new string. I just don't know at whicht point I have to change the value of Isaac Newton to [XXX]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all you need is a string output, you can use

```py
result = []
for t in text_doc:
    if t.ent_type_ == "PERSON":
        result.append("[XXX]")
    else:
        result.append(t.text)
    result.append(t.whitespace_)

res = ''.join(result)
print(res)
```

That is:

- Once the `PERSON` entity is found, append `[XXX]` to the `result` list
- Else, add the current token text
- Append any whitespace after the token if present.

Then, in the end, join the `result` items.